# Login with Steam in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, steam

I have recently been playing around with ASP.NET MVC5 and the new OWIN authentication middleware. 
I want my users to login with their Steam account and password. After a user logs in successfully, I just need the Steam Account Id for further processing. Steam can act as an OpenId Provider [as stated in the documentation](http://steamcommunity.com/dev).

In MVC4 one would [implement a custom OpenIdClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx). It seems to me that in MVC5 the OpenIdClient class has been removed and authentication is configured using the IAppBuilder class which offers methods to login with Facebook, Google and other predefined providers.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any documentation about plugging a custom provider to the new authentication system. Can you give me any instructions or references?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an answer to the bounty that was placed by @Buzinas.

This solution is going to use the NuGet package Owin Security Providers which is available [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/).

Go to the Package Manager Console (`Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`) and install the above package:

```
Install-Package Owin.Security.Providers
```

In your `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` add the proper `using` statement. For Steam, you want

```
using Owin.Security.Providers.Steam;
```

Side note, there are several options available, so this package isn't just for Steam.
[image: Owin.Security.Providers]

In the `ConfigureAuth` method, add `app.UseSteamAuthentication("<<API KEY>>");`

`<<API_KEY>>` should be replaced with the API key you received from [Valve](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)

Comment: Cool, that was definitely not there when I asked the question last year. Good to see that several providers have been added in the meantime. I'll mark this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Docs are still a bit sparse.  One option is to copy-paste a similar existing provider and adapt as needed.

[Recommended way to implement custom authentication provider for owin authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489819/recommended-way-to-implement-custom-authentication-provider-for-owin-authenticat)

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest